# How can a tabelt forget the SSID of a wifi network

Tags: wi-fi, networking, samsung-galaxy-tab-4, hidden, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

We have a product that combines one Galaxy Tab 3 7"or Galaxy Tab 4 7" tablet, both wifi-only, with a Mikrotik RB951G-2hnd router. The Mikrotik has a hidden wifi network so we add it manually to the tablet. Most of the time it works great but for some reason, sometimes the tablet forgets the SSID of the hidden network.

According to our costumers, this happens when there's a power cut and the tablet looses its charge. After the power comes back, the tablet won't connect to our mikrotik device. When checking the WiFi connections on the device configuration the network won't even appear on the list.

This happens only sometimes in some tablets.

How can the device forget a manually entered SSID?

Comment: What is it that you finally want? An explanation or a remedy? Somebody from somewhere can popup and would say that it is a bug and that it is a bug because many people have reported the same problem and they would continue to cite [bug]  like a mantra - there goes the explanation. Would that be enough for you? If not, what would be enough?

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for answering. Even a kid could say it's a bug. That's just a statement. I would like an explanation and if possible a solution.